# apache ignore url query parameter order rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a particular set of URLs to write to different proxy servers based on a query parameter in the url path.
For example, if the URL path sent to apache is
    `http://dest:port/url/one?content=text_string&to_addr=1234456789&from_addr=source_string"`,

I want to be able to rewrite proxy the URL to a different destination based on the `to_addr` value. (If the digits in `toaddr` start with `123` and are followed by `441` or `442`, or `443`, etc. and is followed by seven more digits)

The problem I have is the query parameters can come in any order. Please how can I configure apache so that I can capture the query strings in any order, and reorder them as I need to?